# Python Refactoring - Redundant Functions in multiple classes

Tags: python

Here is my code, but obviously this is redundant since I need to add e.g. func4 to both places of `Context` and `ContextManager`... is there a good way to write it more elegantly?

```py
class Context(object):
    def __init__(self, uuid):
        self.uuid = uuid

    def func1(self):
        print("This is func1")

    def func2(self, arg1):
        print(arg1)

    def func3(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        print(arg1)
        print(arg2)
        print(arg3)


class ContextManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.contexts_by_uuid = {}

    def create_context(self):
        ctx_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
        self.contexts_by_uuid[ctx_uuid] = Context(ctx_uuid)
        return ctx_uuid

    def func1(self, ctx_uuid):
        ctx = self.contexts_by_uuid.get(ctx_uuid)
        return ctx.func1()

    def func2(self, ctx_uuid, arg1):
        ctx = self.contexts_by_uuid.get(ctx_uuid)
        return ctx.func2(arg1)

    def func3(self, ctx_uuid, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        ctx = self.contexts_by_uuid.get(ctx_uuid)
        return ctx.func2(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Comment: Where is the `func4` you are talking about?

Comment: @KlausD. I presume it's just a hypothetical: "What about when I need to add n more methods?"

Comment: @KlausD. What dspencer says is right. That is just an example.

Comment: without more "context" it is hard to say. I don't immediately see why all the `funcs` cannot just live inside the `ContextManager` and then you may delete them from `Context`

Comment: @plumSemPy because Context has more attributes and funcN in Context edit them so having separate classes is clearer

Comment: I see, and why can funcN in `ContextManager` not edit the many attributes in `Context` directly? It seems to me that the `Context` can be something like a `namedtuple` from the `collection` library

Comment: @plumSemPy `Context` also has methods, like `func1`, which cannot (should not...?) be stored in a `namedtuple`.

Comment: @dspencer The gist of my argument is, every method that the `ContextManager` calls as `ctx.funcN`, can just be on `ContextManager`. I don't see the need for this wrapping, even if `Context` has unique methods.

Comment: @plumSemPy It's a good point, but there are reasons why one might want to decouple these two classes. Perhaps `Context` doesn't always have to be used via a `ContextManager`, in which case having to create one would be a pain.

Comment: I agree with you, which is why Im asking for more "context". If Context can be used in isolation and we also want a ContextManager, then although they both have a method with the same name, those methods don't necessarily do the same thing, so I wouldn't refactor. But as it stands, in this tight context, and if we have to refactor then it is redundant. We do need more context from the OP. It is not a straightforward question

Comment: @xyz1.8 Can you provide more details about the real use case of these two classes?

Comment: > why can funcN in ContextManager not edit the many attributes in Context directly?

This is a good idea. I think I was in a hole and couldn't see such simple idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My thought would be to define a method on `ContextManager` which uses `getattr` to access the method from `Context` by name, something like this:

```py
def func(self, func_name, ctx_uuid, *args):
    ctx = self.contexts_by_uuid.get(ctx_uuid)
    return getattr(ctx, func_name)(*args)
```

However, I wouldn't recommend doing this, as it sacrifices readability and makes it impossible for any static checking to ensure code validity. For example, you could very easily try to access a method from `Context` which does not exist.